# How to get all the .pdf and the .epub files across the device storage in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, pdf, dart

I'm trying to create an epub reader app.

On the Homepage, I am trying to list the books with a Horizontal scroll view of the book covers.

For that, I need all the local pdf and epub files. How can I do that efficiently?

Thanks.

Comment: do a web search for `traverse directory` and a keyword of the language you use

Comment: Sure and thanks for your response